# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when run xelatex on centos 6.2

Tags: xetex

I install tex live from iso image: http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CTAN/systems/texlive/Images/texlive.iso.

[image]

But when i run xelatex, it turns out:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I use `gdb xelatex core_file` with the run command:

```
$ gdb xelatex core.16233 
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-50.el6)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

...

(gdb) run
No core file now.
Starting program: /usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/xelatex 
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

My system is:

```
cat /etc/*release
CentOS Linux release 6.2 (Final)
CentOS Linux release 6.2 (Final)
```

Comment: possibly related to this, although the error slightly different https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443489/tex-live-2018-distribution-glibc-prevents-usage

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, it seems tex live2018 do not support centos 6.2.

Comment: You could use [Exodus](https://github.com/intoli/exodus) to bundle all the dependencies on a system which supports TeX Live 2018 and transfer it to your Cent OS machine.

Answer (score 1):

as i answered on the other question, and replied on the tex-live list: everything except those programs which require new icu/poppler can be compiled (xetex, luatex, and a handful of others), and i already did that. i don't know of any way to get a usable xetex binary for centos 6.x; what you tried is more than anyone has done before (as far as i know), and the fact that it doesn't work is sad, but not surprising. good luck.

Comment: There is a way to get XeTeX etc. on Cent OS 6.2 but I don't think it's worth the effort.  In essence you'd have to compile a more recent version of GCC which supports C++11 to compile TeX Live.  But that will not be redistributable because the `libc` has to be the same of newer than what was compiled against, so you'd have to statically link `libc` but that comes with its own set of problems.

Comment: Hi Henri -- yes, agreed, as we previously discussed on the list.